# How to allow the end user to define multiple namespace-extension levels for this pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, javascript-namespaces

Take this code for example:

```
(function(foo) {

    foo.init = function() {};

    // other public/private methods here.

    return foo;

}(window.FOO = window.FOO || {}));
```

I call it like so:

```
FOO.init();
```

Is it possible to allow the user to define what `FOO` is?

In other words, I need to allow multiple instances of `window.FOO`; for example, like `window.BILLY` and `window.BAZ` (or, should it be `window.billy.FOO` and `window.baz.FOO`?).

In other words, is there an elegant way to (allow the user to) namespace a "namespace" using a variation of the above construct and initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to change the above code such that the name of `FOO` is dynamic. You can do that, using the [] property accessor:

```
function initFoo(fooName) {
    (function(foo) {

        foo.init = function() {};

        // other public/private methods here.

        return foo;

    }(window[fooName] = window[fooName] || {}));
}

initFoo('FOO');
initFoo('BILLY');
```

But I'm not sure what sense this would make, your example is very abstract.

Comment: Thank you @fab. Sorry about my example being abstract. I will create a more complete/working example tomorrow and update my post. I will also experiment with your code, and I'm sure I'll be back with more questions. Please stay tuned. Thank you!

Comment: After having reviewed my code, I think I need to finish asking my question on the Stack CodeReview site. Your reply pretty much answers my question and that's a new technique I'd never seen before, so thanks! I agree with your comment though, the example I posted is very abstract and in order for me to get specific, I think the [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site is the place to be.

Answer (score 2):

The `windows.billy.FOO` and `windows.baz.FOO` are preferred.

Have a read through [Addy Osmani's Essential JS Namespacing Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) to get up to speed (most relevant part: Deep object extension).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for tips @oerd! I really appreciate the help. That article is awesome. I'm planning on updating my question tomorrow with the things I've learned from the replies here in the hopes that I can get a little more feedback on my code.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply and article link. I just finished reading through it and there's a ton of awesome information there that should help me get to where I need to be. Once I get a bit further, I'm also going to move my question on Stack's [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site; in order for me to get specific, I'm going to need to post a bunch more code (I was trying to avoid that, hence the reason why my question was a little vague/abstract). Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Check out Addy Osmani's site for more javascript awesomeness ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into RequireJS: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

It may have the end-user functionality you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for tip/linkages! I'll take a closer look at that lib. I'll be back tomorrow with updated code if you're interested to see where I'm going with this. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Thanks again Dimitry! In order to get more specific feedback on my code, I plan on asking the question on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For now though, +1. Cheers! M.